# OpenCV ffmpeg error when compiling on Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg, compilation, libav

When building OpenCV on Ubuntu 18 I have the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

The same procedure used to work on the same machine. All the package necessary seems to be installed.

```
cd ~
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.4.0.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.4.0.zip
unzip opencv.zip
unzip opencv_contrib.zip
mkdir -p ~/opencv-4.4.0/build
cd ~/opencv-4.4.0/build


CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5
cmake \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=$CUDA_ARCH_BIN \
..
```

The error is thrown when running the make command `make -j 15`.

Let me know if you need any other information

Comment: It is trying to link OpenCV with the static version of libavcodec. I see that you are using a custom build of ffmpeg, how did you compile it?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Check if you have some path related to "/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib/" on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable. You can check it launching this bash command:
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: if there is such a path, probably you set it on your .bashrc file. So you can open it launching on your console: gedit ~/.bashrc and then you search for an "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" on it. You should then remove the entry "/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib/", save the file, and launch a new terminal.